# Excel VBA ActiveX Label weird behaviour

Tags: vba, excel

I needed to put multiple Checkboxes on a Worksheet. The standard Checkbox options in Excel FormControl and ActiveX Control are too small. So, I found a work-around using [**`this`**](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T008566_Resizing_Checkboxes.html) link.

Basically you will create an ActiveX Label which will be formatted as Wingdings font. The macro basically changes the character from a empty box Wingdings Chr(168) to a checked box Wingdings Chr(254) when the user clicks on the label.

If you create a label manually and add a code, everything works fine. But I am creating these labels and adding corresponding Click event code using VBA. The labels and codes are getting created BUT it's not displaying Chr(168) the way it supposed to be. Once created, if you click on any label and go to it's property and click on font, font windows will be opened. Even if you don't do anything on this window (since font is already set using VBA) and close it, label will display Chr(168) properly.

Here is my code:

```
Public Function AddChkBox()
    Dim sLabelName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 4  '~~> Actual number is big
        sLabelName = "Label" & (i - 1)
        With Sheets("Input").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Range("B" & i).Left + 5, _
            Top:=Range("B" & i).Top + 3, Width:=60, Height:=13)

            .Name = sLabelName
            .Object.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
            .Object.Font.Size = 16
            .Object.Caption = Chr(168)
            .Object.TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        End With
        Call InsertSub("Input", sLabelName, "Click")
    Next
End Function

Public Function InsertSub(shtName As String, labelName As String, action As String)
    ' Code courtesy @Siddharth Rout
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim VBP As Object, VBC As Object, CM As Object
    Dim strProcName As String
    strProcName = labelName & "_" & action

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(shtName)

    Set VBP = wb.VBProject
    Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents(ws.CodeName)
    Set CM = VBC.CodeModule

    With wb.VBProject.VBComponents( _
        wb.Worksheets(ws.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
            .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc(action, labelName) + 1, _
            String:=vbCrLf & _
                "   If " & labelName & ".Caption = Chr(254) Then" & vbCrLf & _
                "       'box with no checkmark" & vbCrLf & _
                "       " & labelName & ".Caption = Chr(168)" & vbCrLf & _
                "       " & labelName & ".ForeColor = -2147483640" & vbCrLf & _
                "   Else" & vbCrLf & _
                "       'box with a checkmark" & vbCrLf & _
                "       " & labelName & ".Caption = Chr(254)" & vbCrLf & _
                "       " & labelName & ".ForeColor = 32768" & vbCrLf & _
                "   End If"
    End With
End Function
```

Any thoughts on this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the  Font's `Charset`, Wingdings won't work with default charset. Just Change it to 2 and you are all set.

```
//......
            .Name = sLabelName
            .Object.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
            '/ Need to add the charset. Default is 1. Change it to 2.
            .Object.Font.Charset = 2
            .Object.Font.Size = 16
//......
```

Charset --> 1 = DEFAULT_CHARSET

Charset --> 2= SYMBOL_CHARSET

Comment: Yep, you are right. just checked before I got your answer. Still accepted ;)